SSMA: Find settings for filtered unique indexes for NULL-able columns
I am trying to migrate DB from MySQL to SQL Server through SSMA.
Most of the tables within the DB were successfully migrated, but some more complex tables had problems.
So several tables have multiple foreign keys which in addition buit up unique nonclusted indexes (in the MySQL).
These foreign keys could be Nulls (which is allowed in MySQL). (I suppose that it had ON DELETE SET NULL)
In SQL Server however, unique nonclusted index cannot allow any parts of it to be NULL.
While searching for solution I have found a Query, suitable fpor SQLS:
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_your_column_name
ON your_table_name(your_column_name)
WHERE your_column_name IS NOT NULL;
The problem is I do not find how can I influece the Query in the SSMA, so that it writes similar Query.
Does anyone know where could I find such settings in the SSMA?
